# i want to add IF AND in many condition using the following formula, please kindly read it properly the meaning and help me solve the issue

Tags: microsoft-excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKCiV.jpg)if Class is "XI", Stream is "Arts" and Computer is "Yes" Then the Total Fees should be 20000 else if computer is "No" total fees must be only "15000". If class is "XI" Stream is "Science" and computer is "Yes" Total Fees must be "25000" else if computer is "No" then Total Fees must be "20000"....... Continue the same formula till Class "XII" Stream "Science"

Comment: Really long formulas like this can usually be done better a different way. It would be useful to see sample data and expected result

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: a lookup table may be what you want, but as one of the answers point out, the error in the if statement makes it hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just a note: The Headline is for attention, it is not where you put the question, usually. The Body should contain the question, relevant facts, and any code. I strongly recommend that you use the EDIT button to modify your post to make it a clear question following the conventions of this site in order to attract the good answers you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ref: https://www.libreofficehelp.com/if-nested-if-and-or-criteria-in-libreoffice-calc/
... for LibreOffice/Calc's IF()-syntax, the very same as in Excel.

You have

```
IF( AND(expressions),  
  true_value,  
  false_value,  

  IF( AND(...),
  true_value,  
  false_value,  

  IF( AND(...),
    continuation_forever_without_closing_any_IF...
```

All the IF-statements has to have **a closing parenthesis** after `false-value`.
Anything else is simply a glaring "syntax-error".

You can have a new IF() in place of either of true or false-value, but not as a fourth argument to IF(

Answer (score 0):

`IF()` takes three operands: the `condition`, the value for `true`, and the value for `false`. Currently your first `IF()` has more than three operands and can't work.

You need to provide a properly formatted decision tree for us to create the formula. Your current attempt is ambiguous and we don't know what you really want to calculate.